# Was this really serial upvoting?

Tags: support, up-votes

I have a series of puzzles, my 'Clues' series, [starting with this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one).

Yesterday, somebody went and upvoted all of the questions in the series, [including two that I didn't post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4456/scimonster?tab=reputation).

However, now the 50 rep that I gained from it has been reversed, probably due to an automatic script that I remember reading about.

Is this really serial upvoting, or is it just 'series' upvoting?

Comment: Why not both :)?

Comment: As I am reading this post someone is serially upvoting me. So tomorrow I will have a reversal of 115. :D

Comment: @MariaDeleva Also, any upvotes that didn't count because of the repcap will be counted.

Comment: @Mithrandir, good to know. :) Although, it doesn't really matter that much for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even if it's not "serial voting" in the truly bad sense (e.g. sockpuppets), it may still be serial voting in that it goes against SE's policy of "vote for the post, not the person".**

Obviously the automatic algorithm to reverse serial voting isn't perfect: there will always be false positives and false negatives. It's possible to serially upvote someone and not get caught by the algorithm, if you're clever enough about it: e.g. see [this recent scandal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours) on Ask Ubuntu. It's also possible - though **much less likely** - for a well-meaning person to go through a bunch of your questions not because they're yours but because they're closely related (e.g. a sequence of puzzles) and find them all good enough to upvote, and for this honest voting to be reverted by the system.

The serial upvoting reversal algorithm is meant to encourage "*vote for the post, not the person*", and to deter people from going through the profile of someone they like and upvoting all their posts. This may or may not have been what happened here, but in any case the voting pattern was suspicious enough that it was reversed by the system. From [the canonical main meta post about serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/278659):

> Most often when you get unexpectedly serial upvoted, believe it or not, it's just a user trying to give you extra reputation. They saw a post of yours that was extraordinarily helpful to them and they feel that going through your posts systematically and upvoting them is the appropriate way of granting you additional reputation (apparently they've forgotten about the bounty system).
>
> **Should I be concerned about reversal statements on my profile?**
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After all, we can't control the actions of other users. It's very rare where we'd run across a user who was committing the voting fraud themselves on their own account, and in most instances of that, they will have already been dealt with accordingly. You should in no way be concerned with reversal statements in your reputation history.

Comment: *Exactly* about the related posts. The other author of the series had his two puzzles upvoted too. (The voter wouldn't happen to be you, was it? :P)

Comment: @Mithrandir Nope. I did vote on a few of them, but nowhere near all of them. (I'm too experienced with SE to be caught serial voting! ;-) )

Comment: @randal'thor Is that to mean that you do serial vote and just don't get caught? :P

Comment: @dcfyj ... no, just that I wouldn't go through a whole sequence of related puzzles upvoting them all too quickly if they happened to be by the same person.

Comment: @randal'thor _aggressively investigates account_